# Why is the convolutional filter flipped in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I don't understand why there is the need to flip filters when using convolutional neural networks.

According to the lasagne documentation,

> flip_filters : bool (default: True)
>
> Whether to flip the filters before sliding them over the input,
> performing a convolution (this is the default), or not to flip them
> and perform a correlation. Note that for some other convolutional
> layers in Lasagne, flipping incurs an overhead and is disabled by
> default – check the documentation when using learned weights from
> another layer.

What does that mean? I never read about flipping filters when convolving in any neural network book. Would someone clarify, please?

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27451/52433